# extracting a non-contiguous submatrix in numpy

Tags: python, numpy

Is there any simple and efficient way of extracting a non-contiguous submatrix in NumPy?
for example, I have a matrix of size 4X4

```
A=[ [1, 2, 3, 4]
    [5, 6, 7, 8]
    [9, 10, 11, 12]
    [13, 14, 15, 16]]
```

and I have two lists: `r=[1,2]`(rows) and `c=[0,3]` (columns)
so I want the submatrix:

```
B=[[5, 8]
   [9, 12]]
```

Thanks

Comment: add more test cases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`np.ix_`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.ix_.html):

```
import numpy as np
A=np.array([ [1, 2, 3, 4],[5, 6, 7, 8],[9, 10, 11, 12],[13, 14, 15, 16]])
r=[1,2]
c=[0,3]
A[np.ix_(r,c)]
```

Output:

```
array([[ 5,  8],
       [ 9, 12]])
```